# ASP.NET connection string encryption

Tags: asp.net, iis, encryption, connection-string

The answers I found to this issue didn't seem to work.  This is a difficult item to find information about on MSDN and in general.

I am using Windows Server 2003, IIS 6, Dot.Net 3.5 and Visual Studio 2008.

I need to know how to encrypt a connection string for an Asp.Net web application.

Comment: You should separate this into a question and an answer.

Comment: You may want to pose this as a question then answer it and accept it.

Comment: Thanks SLaks and AmitApollo.  I have done that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is my solution to this for Windows Server 2003 and IIS 6 and .Net 3.5 and Visual Studio 2008. Since the encryption is machine-specific, it **HAS** to be run on the web server.

Encryption Command (change PROJECT_NAME to your web app folder name):

c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis -pef "connectionStrings" "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\PROJECT_NAME"

The second command gives the ASPNET account access to the NetFrameworkConfigurationKey in machine.config.

c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis -pa "NetFrameworkConfigurationKey" "ASPNET"

The third command gives the NT Authority\Network Service account access to the NetFrameworkConfigurationKey.

c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis -pa "NetFrameworkConfigurationKey" "NT Authority\Network Service"

I hope this helps someone.